# Create video stream from tiny endless files

Tags: sockets, video, ffmpeg

I have a client sending endless (or at least large unknown amount) tiny webm files (around 2 seconds each) using websocket, video content is base64 encoded, and I want to create a live video stream from them.
So it'll be like this:

1. Client open web socket.
2. Client sends first file.
3. Server starts streaming the file online.
4. Client sends second file.
5. Server *appends* the video with the second file.
6. Repeat 5&6 until web socket closes.

Now, I've already done the part for websocket on server/client side, and decoding the content from base64 is no problem, but completely stuck on the stream conversion part, far as I've looked the best option would be running FFMPEG, but can't find a way to give it endless stream to convert.

P.S: running on Windows machine, socket server is nodejs-websocket.